# How to make grid column fill the entire space when there's too little content?

Tags: css, grid

I have `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 0px fit-content(780px) 0px 1fr 1fr;` but, of course, if I have too little content, the column does not fill the entire space I want it to: 780px.

How can I keep the grid responsive and at the same time make the column to fill the entire space even when there's too little content?

Comment: That does not make sense. You want it to fit the content but still be 780px? So just make it 780px wide. It won't be responsive but it will be as wide as you want it to be. Or perhaps you are looking for some form of minimax?

Comment: I see. Please, tell me if this makes sense: Maybe I could use media queries to change fit-content(780px) for desktop into fit-content(320px) for mobiles? And about minimax: there's a way to obtain what I'm asking?

Comment: So, it seems that with minmax(0px, 780px) I can solve this. I hope this makes sense. If anyone has a better solution please let me know. Thanks.